# ObservableObject Set method only fires if value is different

Tags: kendo-mvvm

This looks like a bug, or at least poor documentation.

The [kendo docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#events-set) state:

***set event***
Fired when the set method is invoked.
The set event is raised before the field value is updated. Calling the get method from the event handler will return the old value. Calling e.preventDefault will prevent the update of the field and the change event will not be raised.

This [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/imeRu) demonstrates that the set event is only fired when the set value is different to the existing value.

It would appear to me that, to be more correct, this method should be renamed "PreChange" and a new "Set" method created that actually fires when Set is invoked, as per the documentation.

Am I correct in stating this is a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I got your point. Don't know if this could be a bug or not...
Just my 2 cents: I feel like it's a choice poor documented.

If you try to set an identical value, it seems the set event doesn't even trigger!
It's similar to the change event... if you write the same value, the event won't trigger.